# React Native useState not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-state

Can anyone seem to figure this out as I'm really struggling, I have been trying to use useState, this is the arrays i have so far

```
const Body = (props) => {
  const [workoutText, setText] = useState();
  const [setsText, setText1] = useState();
  const [workoutTextItems, setWorkoutItems] = useState([]);


  const handleAddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setWorkoutItems([...workoutTextItems, workoutText, setsText])
    setText(null);
    setText1(null);
  }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I input my data into a TextInput, they dont get stored as expected, I'm pretty new to this so I might be doing something completely wrong but this is my code for the TextInput's

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        keyboardVerticalOffset={-500}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
      >
        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
          <View style={styles.modalWeight}>
            <TextInput maxLength={28} placeholder="Workout" value={workoutText} onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
            />
            <TextInput
              value={setsText}
              onChangeText={text1 => setText1(text1)}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              placeholder="Sets"
            ></TextInput>
            <TextInput keyboardType="number-pad" placeholder="Reps"></TextInput>
            <TextInput keyboardType="number-pad" placeholder="Weight"></TextInput>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
              <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This is the code to map the data

```
 workoutTextItems.map((text, text1, index) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                <WorkoutTile
                  text={text}
                  text1={text1}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          })

const WorkoutTile = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.workoutName}>{props.text}</Text>
      <View style={styles.srwTitles}>
        <Text>{props.text1}</Text>
        <Text>reps</Text>
        <Text>weight</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[This is the output on my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfCAa.png)

So the numbers on the left hand side are meant to be where it says sets but that just seems to be a counter for some reason and all my data is getting put on the left hand side

The data getting stored in text is all of it but I want just the sets to get into text1 and just the workout name in text

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in how you're storing your data. Specifically in this line:
`setWorkoutItems([...workoutTextItems, workoutText, setsText])`

Breaking it down:

1. `...workoutTextItems` is adding all the elements previously stored in the state array - good so far
2. You're adding workoutText and setsText as *two seperate items*
3. When parsing the array with `workoutTextItems.map((text, text1, index) =>` You assign the value of the element to text, then the index of the element to text1. This is why you have alternating workout names and sets in the title column, and an index row in the sets column.

You should be able to easily fix this by changing the original line to:
`setWorkoutItems([...workoutTextItems, [workoutText, setsText]])`

Although, it might be worth exploring storing your data as an object for each row for the sake of best practices, readablity, and scalability.

Hope this helps!